# How to simultaneously Zip dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m trying to build on two functions (print_pd_groupby, deliver_files_smartopen) below to correctly zip up all 3 data frames according to the column called “class” below. Is there a way to process all 3 data frames simultaneously, and zip up the data correctly in their own directories? Thank you.

```
import os.path
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import pandas as pd
import smart_open
import tempfile
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path



df = pd.DataFrame ({
  "calories": [420, 380, 390, 1000, 2000],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45, 60, 100],
  "type": ['jump rope', 'dance','weight train', 'trapeze', 'running'],
  "class": ['struc/class/A_123/','struc/class/B_123/','struc/class/C_123/','struc/class/D_123/', 'struc/class/B_123/']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame ({
  "names": ['Ailish', 'Bob', 'Tara', 'Carl', 'Caleb', 'Tyler'],
  "city": ['Boston', 'Salt Lake', 'Houston', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles','Seattle'],
  "state": ['MA', 'UT','TX', 'CA', 'CA','WA'],
  "class": ['struc/class/A_123/some_name','struc/class/B_123/some_name','struc/class/C_123/some_name','struc/class/D_123/some_name', 'struc/class/B_123/some_name', 'struc/class/C_123/some_name']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame ({
  "hobby": ['reading', 'swimming', 'tv'],
  "relative": ['dad','mom','grandparents'],
  "class": ['struc/class/A_123/some_name/some_info/','struc/class/B_123/some_name/some_info/','struc/class/B_123/some_name/some_info']
})

folder_id =  'class'
folderlist =  df['class'].drop_duplicates().to_list()
folderlist2 = df2['class'].drop_duplicates().to_list()
folderlist3 = df3['class'].drop_duplicates().to_list()


def print_pd_groupby(X, grp=None):

    if grp is None:
        for k,i in X:
            return df_frame
    else:
        for j in grp:
            #print(X)
            df_frame = (X.get_group(j))
            #print(df_frame)
            return df_frame
        # return X.get_group(grp[0])

def deliver_files_smartopen (zip_name, path_of_file):
    with smart_open.open(zip_name, 'wb') as fout:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(fout, 'w') as zf:
            for item in folderlist:
                    dataframe_holder = print_pd_groupby(dfg,grp = [item])
                    writePath = (item + path_of_file)
                    df_frame = dataframe_holder.to_csv(index=False)
                    zf.writestr(writePath, df_frame)
                    
        zf.close()
    fout.close()

# I need to find a way to create all three dataframes and zip them up here
# How can I change the functions above to do that?

dfg = df.groupby(folder_id)
my_zip = 'someexample.zip'
my_extension = 'class_data.csv'
deliver_files_smartopen(my_zip,my_extension)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly. What speaks against making a bigger dataframe joined via a substring of class if thats what you want to create the zips for?